# saving finetuned model locally

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to understand how to save a fine-tuned model locally, instead of pushing it to the hub.

I've done some tutorials and at the last step of fine-tuning a model is running `trainer.train()` .  And then the instruction is usually: `trainer.push_to_hub`

But what if I don't want to push to the hub?  I want to save the model locally, and then later be able to load it from my own computer into future task so I can do inference without re-tuning.

How can I do that?

eg: Initially load a model from hugging face:

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=5)
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=small_train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=small_eval_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

Somehow save the new trained model locally, so that next time I can pass

```
model = 'some local directory where model and configs (?) got saved'
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [`save_model` method](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.save_model):

```py
trainer.save_model("path/to/model")
```

Or alternatively, the [`save_pretrained` method](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.save_pretrained):

```py
model.save_pretrained("path/to/model")
```

Then, when reloading your model, specify the path you saved to:

```py
AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("path/to/model")
```

Comment: is this different from `Trainer.save_model()` , i.e. does it save the same thing?

Comment: @yulGM, yes that should give you the same result, I've edited the answer to include this as well. You might also want to have a look at the [`output dir` `Trainer` argument](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.output_dir).

Comment: What is the difference between these 2 methods? The docs for `save_model` says `Will only save from the main process` but what does it mean?

Comment: @ruslaniv I suppose that that's referring to when multiple processes are used to train the model.

Comment: This only saves the adapter layer, but I'm trying to figure out how to save the full fine tuned model. So I don't have a separate adapter layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using

```
trainer.model._save_pretrained("file_path/model_name")
```